# Determining best method to traverse a table and update another table

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7, bde

I am using Delphi 7, BDE, and Interbase (testing), Oracle (Production).

I have two tables (Master, Responses)

I need to step through the Responses table, use its Master_Id field to look it up in Master table (id) for matching record and update a date field in the Master table with a date field in the Responses table

Can this be done in SQL, or do i actually have to create two TTables or TQueries and step through each record?

Example:

Open two tables (Table1, Table2)

```
with Table1 do
begin
 first;
 while not EOF do
 begin
  //get master_id field
  //locate in id field in table 2
  //edit record in table 2
  next;
 end;
end;
```

thanks

Comment: post the DDL for the tables, someone will write the one query for you

Comment: NEVER, EVER, EVER loop to process rows... ok, not never, sometimes you have to but it's super rare... like GOTO.

Comment: Oh, and learn some SQL... it's an amazing language... one command with sooo much power.

Comment: that was an encouragement not a critique.

Comment: You can't use Interbase as a test database for a Oracle production database. There are many differences in the SQL they support.

Comment: BDE is pretty old and unsupported, if this is a new project, consider using a current and supported database connection layer, like dbExpress

Comment: Two sidesteps: you should try to avoid the BDE (if you use it, only use it for local file based databases like Paradox or dBase), and try to avoid `with` by putting the code in the `with` block into a function. OTOH: good question (+1); you should do this in SQL as the answers shown you.

Comment: BDE doesn't matter here. As long as the proper SQL is sent to the database you could even use a pidgeon to send the query and everything would be fine. Moreover dbExpress in Delphi 7 is full of bugs, and the Oracle driver a joke. SQLLINKS then worked far better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One slight modification to Chris' query, throw in a where clause to select only the records that need the update. Otherwise it will set the rest of the dates to NULL

```
UPDATE Master m
SET 
    m.date = (SELECT r.date FROM Reponses r WHERE r.master_id = m.id) 
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT master_id FROM Responses)
```

Updated to use aliases to avoid confusion which col comes from which table.
This is not ready made, copy-past'able query as UPDATE syntax differs from database to database.
You may need to consult your database sql reference for JOIN in UPDATE statement syntax.

When there are multiple responses to same master entry

```
UPDATE Master m 
SET      m.date = (
    SELECT MAX(r.date) FROM Reponses r WHERE r.master_id = m.id)  
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT master_id FROM Responses)
```

I used MAX() you can use whatever suits your business.
Again invest some time understanding SQL. Its hardly a few days effort. Get PLSQL Complete reference if you are into Oracle

Comment: Im alittle confused here. It would be ID for Master table and Master_Id for Reponses table. Is this still correct with your answer?

Comment: This does not work for me. It goes to exception on the ExecSQL command

Comment: General SQL Error - Multiple rows in singleton select.

Comment: That was to show you a way, it wasnt ment to be a runnable query. Updated answer with more clarification.

Comment: Well, i did state it was for interbase and orac;e. If you can get it so it works in Intgerbase, that will be suffice

Comment: even with your update, i still get the : "General SQL Error - Multiple rows in singleton select"

Comment: That means there are multiple response entries for a given master id. Depending on your business, you may want to use last response date in such cases, see update again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL (changing names to fit your situation)

UPDATE Master m
  SET date = ( SELECT date FROM Responses WHERE id = m.id )

Comment: as in my comment above, wouldn't this be:   UPDATE Master m SET bank_cleared = ( SELECT bank_date FROM Responses WHERE master_id = m.id )

Comment: Yes, I just wasn't 100% sure what your field names were.

Comment: @Chris - This does not work for me. It goes to exception on the ExecSQL command

Comment: Well, you should post the exception then :) Hard to guess it as long as it is on your machine...

Comment: Yes, please.  What is the exception?

Comment: General SQL Error - Multiple rows in singleton select.   This message occurs for both Chris Hogan's and d-live's answers.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the relation from Master to Responses is 1-to-many, so the subquery returns multiple values for bank_date but the main query is expecting a single value to assign to bank_cleared.  You'll have to adjust the subquery to return a single date, for example change "SELECT bank_date" to "SELECT MAX(bank_date)".

Comment: Well, that worked without error, unfortunately, it filled in the master table's bank_cleared date with the max date.  There were 1/26/11, 1/27/11, and 1/28/11 dates that should have been updated, but the field was populated with all 1/28/11 dates - thanks